# Function calls in objective C and C++

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, function, methods

I have some general question about Objective C, I have read the basics of Objective C online and in some books, I have got a doubt there where I came across function calls. In Objective C passing a method to object like this...

```
eg: [object method]; // here object is objective C class.
```

it will be considered as message passing. If so what about if I made a normal C++ call like this...

```
eg: object->method(); // here object is C++ class.
```

this also a message passing in objective C or it will be treated like normal C++ way.

thanks for your clarifications...

Comment: You probably need an Objective-C++ to be able to write `object->method()` and Objective C has a more dynamic way for method invocations (à la Smalltalk, using method dictionaries lookups).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `object` is a C++ object, then `object->method()` will be a regular C++ call. Generally the two (C++ and Objective-C) are distinct, though in some cases you can intermix the two using ["Objective-C++"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B).